# Pass value to one input from another

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

There's a third party code that performs this search:

Before entering a value:

```
<div class="mb-m" id="dd-company-name-input" data-doublethedonation-widget-id="G__2">
    <div class="dtd-streamlined-plugin">
      <input type="hidden" name="doubledonation_status" value="no_interaction">
      <input type="hidden" name="doublethedonation_status" value="no_interaction">
      <input type="hidden" name="doublethedonation_entered_text">
      <input type="hidden" name="doubledonation_company_id">
      <input type="hidden" name="doublethedonation_company_id">
      <input type="hidden" name="doubledonation_company_name">
      <input type="hidden" name="doublethedonation_company_name">

      <div style="width: 100%; margin-bottom: 0px;" class="dtd-search-box">
        <div aria-live="assertive" style="display: block; font-size: 0px; color: rgb(255, 255, 255); opacity: 0; position: absolute; height: 0px; margin: 0px; z-index: -99999;"></div>
        <div aria-live="polite" style="display: block; font-size: 0px; color: rgb(255, 255, 255); opacity: 0; position: absolute; height: 0px; margin: 0px; z-index: -99999;"></div>
        <input role="listbox" aria-expanded="false" name="doublethedonation_company_name_input" autocomplete="new-password" type="text" style="width: 100%;" id="dd-input" class="dtd-search-input form-control BBFormTextbox" aria-label="Search company" placeholder="Search company name...">
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
```

after selected from search list:

```
<div class="mb-m" id="dd-company-name-input" data-doublethedonation-widget-id="G__2">
    <div class="dtd-streamlined-plugin">
      <input type="hidden" name="doubledonation_status" value="found">
      <input type="hidden" name="doublethedonation_status" value="found">
      <input type="hidden" name="doublethedonation_entered_text" value="goog">
      <input type="hidden" name="doubledonation_company_id" value="94">
      <input type="hidden" name="doublethedonation_company_id" value="94">
      <input type="hidden" name="doubledonation_company_name" value="Google Inc.">
      <input type="hidden" name="doublethedonation_company_name" value="Google Inc.">

      <p class="dtd-company-selected">Company selected: <strong class="dtd-company-selected-name">Google Inc.</strong>. <span class="wrongcompany">
          <a href="javascript:void(0);">Select a different company</a>
        </span>
      </p>
      
    </div>
```

Now I want to pass the value from `name="doubledonation_company_name"` to a different input, let's say `<input id="eName" value="something">`

I tried to trigger the event by

```
jQuery('input[name="doublethedonation_company_name_input"]').change(function() {};
```

but it didn't work, maybe because the element itself disappears from the DOM after the selection is made.

Comment: Are you certain your function was bound to the input? Try a different event like "click". You can also inspect the bound event handlers through the browser's dev tools.

Comment: `jQuery('input[name="doublethedonation_company_name_input"]').cha...` You don't have an input element with the name `doublethedonation_company_name_input`. Should you be using: `jQuery('input[name="doublethedonation_company_name"]').cha...`?